# Compute the minimum of a pair of vectors

Tags: r

If I have a vector `c(1,2,3)` and another vector of the same length `c(1,4,1)` . Is there some way to find the minimum of each pair of numbers in the list pair? i.e. have a function that returns `c(1,2,1`)` I don't want to use any apply function or loops because my vectors will be very big and looping through them would take a long time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want `pmin()`:

```
> x <- c(1,2,3)
> y <- c(1,4,1)
> pmin(x,y)
[1] 1 2 1
```