# Minimum of 2 vectors in R

Tags: r, for-loop, min

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compute the minimum of a pair of vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770535/compute-the-minimum-of-a-pair-of-vectors)

I have two vectors of the same length:

```
a <- rnorm(40)
b <- rnorm(40)
```

Now, I want to create a third vector c which has a each point the minor value of a and b.
This could be a solution:

```
for (i in 1:40)
{c[i] <- min(a[i],b[i])}
```

However, I guess there is an easier way to do this.

Comment: Related (and found on the first page of search results for "min vectors"): [vectorialized parallel max() and min()?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5591593/271616), 
[Compute the minimum of a pair of vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7770535/271616), [max and min functions that are similar to colMeans](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7824912/271616)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is exactly what `pmin` is for... which is documented in `?min`.

```
a <- rnorm(40)
b <- rnorm(40)
minab <- pmin(a,b)
```

Answer (score 4):

Joshua's answer is without doubt the best solution for your question. However, I sometimes personally like to use simple tools and create my own piece of code or function. Here is another way of solving the problem:

```
apply(data.frame(v1 = rnorm(40), v2 = rnorm(40)),1,min)
```