# Finding maximum of two vectors without a loop?

Tags: r, vectorization

If there are two vectors, say `x` and `y`.

```
for (i in 1:length(x))
   z[i] = max(x[i],y[i])
```

Can you please help me to perform this without using a loop?

Comment: don't forget to consider clicking "accept" on an answer that satisfactorily answers your questions ...

Comment: Related: [Compute the minimum of a pair of vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7770535/271616)

Comment: This is documented in `?max`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming that the vectors `x` and `y` are of the same length, `pmax` is your function.

```
z = pmax(x, y)
```

If the lengths differ, the `pmax` expression will return different values than your loop, due to recycling.

Answer (score 2):

For completeness sake I include a solution which uses `apply`:

```
Z = cbind(x,y)
apply(Z, 1, max)
```

I don't know how the different solutions compare in terms of speed, but, @JevgenijsStrigins, you could check quite easily.

Comment: I agree, but I added `apply` because it is much more flexible in terms of the functions it can apply.

Comment: sure. `library(benchmark); set.seed(101); x <- runif(1000); y <- runif(1000); benchmark(apply(cbind(x,y),1,max),pmax(x,y))` shows that `pmax` is about 40x faster (don't know how much of that is the cost of `cbind()`)

Comment: There might be some overhead because of `cbind`, but I cannot imagine that it would lead to a 40 times decrease in speed.